# NoValueFactoryException when using Zeroc Ice with java

Tags: java, ice

I am using ZeroC Ice in my project. I have a problem with the following exception:

```
com.zeroc.Ice.NoValueFactoryException
   reason = "no value factory found and compact format prevents slicing (the sender should use the sliced format instead)"
   type = "::test::DataExt"
at com.zeroc.Ice.InputStream$EncapsDecoder11.skipSlice(InputStream.java:3120)
at com.zeroc.Ice.InputStream$EncapsDecoder11.readInstance(InputStream.java:3333)
at com.zeroc.Ice.InputStream$EncapsDecoder11.readValue(InputStream.java:2881)
at com.zeroc.Ice.InputStream.readValue(InputStream.java:1933)
at org.megacinol.test.DataListHelper.read(DataListHelper.java:48)
at org.megacinol.test.TestClass._iceD_testSth(TestClass.java:58)
at org.megacinol.test.TestClass._iceDispatch(TestClass.java:106)
at com.zeroc.IceInternal.Incoming.invoke(Incoming.java:221)
at com.zeroc.Ice.ConnectionI.invokeAll(ConnectionI.java:2706)
at com.zeroc.Ice.ConnectionI.dispatch(ConnectionI.java:1292)
at com.zeroc.Ice.ConnectionI.message(ConnectionI.java:1203)
at com.zeroc.IceInternal.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:412)
at com.zeroc.IceInternal.ThreadPool.access$500(ThreadPool.java:7)
at com.zeroc.IceInternal.ThreadPool$EventHandlerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:781)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

My slice file looks like this:

```
[["underscore"]]
[["java:package:org.megacinol"]]

module test
{
    class Data
    {
        string name;
        string profession;
    }

    ["java:serializable:temp.Player"]
    sequence<byte> Player;

    class DataExt extends Data
    {
        Player player;
    }

    ["java:type:java.util.ArrayList<Data>"] sequence<Data> DataList;

    interface TestClass
    {
        void testSth(DataList data);
    }
}
```

After some experiments and debugging, I've figured out, that removing

```
[["java:package:org.megacinol"]]
```

solves the problem.

I can replace this metadata with nested module declarations, but I would rather stick to the metadata approach.

Is there any other way to solve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure this with `Ice.Package.` configuration property as explained in [documentation](https://doc.zeroc.com/ice/latest/language-mappings/java-mapping/client-side-slice-to-java-mapping/customizing-the-java-mapping#id-.CustomizingtheJavaMappingv3.7-JavaPackageConfigurationProperties)

So for your sample you need to set the configuration property

```
Ice.Package.test=org.megacinol
```